# getting an error "Invalid command 'SSLProxyCheckPeerCN'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, proxy, mod-proxy

i need to load a form in my website and i am getting an error while i include the following htaccess code and i don't know how to solve this error..

the htaccess code

```
     SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/auto/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

and i am getting an error in the server log as:

"Invalid command 'SSLProxyCheckPeerCN', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

how can i solve this problem, any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSL module isn't loaded most probably. Uncomment the following in your `httpd.conf` file

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```